# Which one is the Sobolev norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Which one is the $W^{3,2}$-norm of a function $u(x,y)$?

A:  $(\int |u|^3+(u_x^2+u_y^2)^{3/2}+(u_{xx}^2+u_{yy}^2+u_{xy}^2+u_{yx}^2)^{3/2} \, dx \, dy)^{1/3}$?

B: $(\int |u|^3+|u|_{x}^3+|u|_{y}^3+|u|_{xy}^3+|u|_{yx}^3+|u|_{yy}^3+|u|_{xx}^3 \, dx \, dy)^{1/3}$

I have been confused by the notation of my book. My book uses $|Du|$ to denote $(u_x^2+u_y^2）^{1/2}$. I am not $100\%$ sure which one is correct.

Comment: In the standard notation, neither of those. It is the sum of the $L^2$ norms of $f$ and all of its partial derivatives in all combinations up to third order. Or something equivalent to this (there are lots of small variations you can make). The second thing you wrote would be a form of the $W^{2,3}$ norm.

Comment: Which book are you currently reading? If you are reading L.C. Evans, I might help a bit

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra Yes, I am readding Evans' book.  In the appendix of his book, it states clearly that $|D^α|$ means the square root of the sum of the squares of all deriatives of order α.   Also, $||D^αu||$ means || |D^αu| || in his book. I am so confused..   I am not sure what the absolute value sign mean anymore. I guess the second one that I wrote make more sense? it is simply the sum of the $||*||^p$ of all deriatives up to certain order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are working in $W^{k,p}$ with $p=3$, so in $W^{2,3}$ and **not** $W^{3,2}$.

The second one (but putting the derivative indices within the absolute value) is the correct Sobolev norm. We have

$$\|u\|_{W^{2,3}}=\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq2}\int|D^\alpha u|^3\,dx\,dy\right)^\frac{1}{3}=\left(\int\sum_{|\alpha|\leq2}|D^\alpha u|^3\,dx\,dy\right)^\frac{1}{3}=\left(\int|u|^3+|u_{x}|^3+|u_{y}|^3+|u_{xy}|^3+|u_{yx}|^3+|u_{yy}|^3+|u_{xx}|^3 \, dx \, dy\right)^{1/3}.$$

---

Please note that when we have $\alpha=(0,2)$, we mean $D^\alpha u=u_{yy}$. In the same way $D^{(0,0)} u=u$, $D^{(1,0)} u=u_{x}$, $D^{(1,1)} u=u_{xy}$, and so on, as long as we have $|\alpha|\leq 2$ (the sum of vector elements is at most $2$). This is very different from $$|D^ku|=\left(\sum_{|\alpha|=k}|D^\alpha u|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2},$$
where $k$ is an integer and not a vector.

If $p=2$, then we actually do have
$$\|u\|_{W^{k,2}}^2=\|u\|_{L^2}^2+\|Du\|_{L^2}^2+\|D^2u\|_{L^2}^2+\ldots+\|D^ku\|_{L^2}^2,$$ which resembles closely your first case (where $\|D^ku\|_{L^p}:=\||D^ku|\|_{L^p}$).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @JohnnyChen Great to hear that! I edited my answer to your other question, so my point should be more clear now and less chaotic.